# flask unit test: how to test request from logged in user

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, flask-login

I'm writing some unit tests for my Flask web application and I'm trying to test the differences in the response between a request made by an anonymous user and a logged in user.

I'm using the `Flask-Login` extension to implement the user login/logout.

Obviously I'm able to perform an anonymous request, but how do I simulate a request from a logged in user?

I thought it was enough to send in the headers the `session` cookie, but it's not working.

```
headers = Headers({'Cookie':['WEBSITE_ID=%s; Domain=adsabs.harvard.edu; expires=Thu, 25-Apr-2213 16:53:22 GMT; Path=/' % cookie_value, 
                             'WEBSITE_ID=%s; Domain=.adsabs.harvard.edu; expires=Thu, 25-Apr-2213 16:53:22 GMT; Path=/' % cookie_value,
                             'session="A VERY LONG STRING"; Path=/; HttpOnly',
                 ]})
rv = app.test_client().get('/', headers=headers)
```

Where the session cookie value is a value I got from a real login in my browser.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Flask-Login looks for `user_id` in the session, you can set this in the tests using [`session_transaction`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/#accessing-and-modifying-sessions):

```
with app.test_client() as c:
    with c.session_transaction() as sess:
        sess['user_id'] = 'myuserid'
        sess['_fresh'] = True # https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#fresh-logins
    resp = c.get('/someurl')
```

Where `myuserid` is the id of your [user object](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Login/#your-user-class).

Comment: Do you know why if I send a cookie in the request after modifying the session, the application doesn't see it? Is it because when I modify the session I already send some headers or what?

Answer (score 0):

DazWorrall's answer worked when I copied it ~2019 but when I updated to a recent version of Flask and Flask-Login I needed to prefix an underscore on user_id, ie `sess['user_id'] = 'myuserid'`. Even better, with https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/pull/431 there is an abstraction so tests can now look like:

```py
   test_app.test_client_class = FlaskLoginClient
   user = my_model.User.query.get(1)
   with test_app.test_client(user=user) as c:
      c.get('/admin/place/edit/?id=3')  # Request is logged in
```