# flask unit test: send cookies after modifying the session

Tags: python, session, cookies, flask, flask-login

I'm writing some unit tests for my flask application and I need to simulate a request from a logged in user (I'm using flask login).

I learned  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238462/flask-unit-test-how-to-test-request-from-logged-in-user) that to do this I need to modify the session and add the user id and a `_fresh` parameter:

```
with app.test_client() as c:
    with c.session_transaction() as sess:
        sess['user_id'] = 'myuserid'
        sess['_fresh'] = True
    resp = c.get('/someurl')
```

My problem is that I need to send some other cookies together with the request. 
Something like

```
headers = Headers({'Cookie':'MYCOOKIE=cookie_value;'})
with app.test_client() as c:
    with c.session_transaction() as sess:
        sess['user_id'] = 'myuserid'
        sess['_fresh'] = True
    resp = c.get('/someurl', headers=headers)
```

but when I perform this request the session "disappears" together with the variables I set.

I think (and someone else on IRC has the same idea) it's because my explicit definition of the cookie header overwrites the one containing the `session` cookie.

My question is: is there a way to set my cookie without removing the `session` one?

If not, is there a way to extract the `session` cookie after I modify the session so that I can add it manually to the list of cookies in the `headers` object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the solution was much easier than I thought.

The `test client` object has a method `set_cookie`, so the code should simply be:

```
with app.test_client() as c:
    with c.session_transaction() as sess:
        sess['user_id'] = 'myuserid'
        sess['_fresh'] = True
    c.set_cookie('localhost', 'MYCOOKIE', 'cookie_value')
    resp = c.get('/someurl')
```

Comment: @SeanVieira I need to wait 2 days before I can do it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
with app.test_client() as c:
    with c.session_transaction() as sess:
        sess['user_id'] = 'myuserid'
        sess['_fresh'] = True
    resp = make_response(redirect('/someurl'))
    resp.set_cookie('MYCOOKIE', cookie_value)
```

Comment: `make_response` works in an `application context` and it cannot be used in the way you said

Comment: but I just saw that c has a `set_cookie` method... so maybe I solved the problem! Thanks for the hint