# Unit testing Flask function (with logged in user)

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I'm new to Python and Flask but I'm gradually getting to grips with it. I've got so far into building an app and I'm now thinking I should start some unit testing. I really can't get my head around it though. I've read various docs, posts and examples but I can't seem to transfer this to my own code. I'm hoping if someone can show me how to write a test for one of my functions then things will fall into place. It's very tempting at this stage to ignore it and press on building my app.

```
@app.route('/user/<nickname>/create_bike', methods = ['GET', 'POST'] )
@login_required
def create_bike(nickname):
    user = User.query.filter_by(nickname = nickname).first()
    bikes = user.bikes.all()
    bikecount = user.bikes.count()
    form = CreateBike()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if bikecount < user.bike_allowance:
            # let user create a bike
            newbike = Bikes(bikename = form.bikename.data, 
                user_id = g.user.id, shared = SHARED )
            db.session.add(newbike)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Your new bike has been created')
            return redirect(url_for('create_bike', nickname = nickname))
        else:
            flash("You have too many bikes")
    return render_template('create_bike.html',
        user = user,
        form = form
        )
```

**UPDATE - Here's my working test**

```
def test_create_bike(self):
    u = User(nickname = 'john', email = 'john@example.com', account_type = "tester")
    db.session.add(u)
    db.session.commit()
    # login user
    with self.app as c:
        with c.session_transaction() as sess:
            sess['user_id'] = int(u.get_id())
            # http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Login/#fresh-logins
            sess['_fresh'] = True
        rv = c.post('/user/john/create_bike', data = dict(
            bikename = 'your new bike',
            user_id = sess['user_id'],
            shared = 1
        ), follow_redirects = True)
        assert 'Your new bike has been created' in rv.data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is likely failing because that view requires a logged in user, and since you arent passing in any session data, you are being redirected to the login page (the `data` argument to `.post` is form data, available in `request.form` in your view). Before your assertion you can see what the response is to help you along the way:

```
print rv.status_code
print rv.location #None if not a redirect
```

There's some documentation around sessions in tests [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/#accessing-and-modifying-sessions), and if you're using Flask-Login like it looks you are, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238462/flask-unit-test-how-to-test-request-from-logged-in-user/16238537#16238537) shows you how to set the session up so you get a logged in user

Comment: This was indeed the problem, I've got my test working now. Thanks for a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

Checking if the html page contains some piece of data that should be there is one the most common scenarios in testing web apps. You just need to repeat for all the other pages that you create. You can also add tests to see that creating a user follows all the validation rules that you've setup or that the username field is unique etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this test returns an assertion error. I feel like I'm working blind, it's difficult to know why the test is failing so I'm resorting to trial and error which isn't getting me very far.

Comment: Try another string in the page in the assert statement. Flash messages are generated dynamically, so they need a JS runtime like selenium to be testable.

Comment: Flash messages are stored in the session and can absolutely be rendered server side: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/flashing/