# Programmatically Flask login during tests

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

How can I **programmatically** (without posting credentials to the login page like I'm currently doing) login an user during tests using [Flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)?

I tried the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16238537/267719) (which seems the only one for a programmatically login), but in my case it doesn't work, I get a 302 response because the `unauthorized_handler` is triggered like if the user is not logged in (my handler redirects to the login page if user is not authenticated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved! And IMO I think is the most elegant and easy solution possible:

```
# we need this:
from flask_login import encode_cookie

# ...then in the test:    
with self.client.session_transaction():
    self.client.set_cookie(
        self.app.config['SERVER_NAME'], 
        'remember_token', 
        encode_cookie(user_id)
    )
    # assertions here... User is now logged in! \0/
```

The actual code is just 2 lines (here I formatted just for readability :P)